# Why can't I use a condition as a case in a switch-statement on an int?

Tags: c#, c, switch-statement

I have this code

```
int a = 0;
int b = 2;
switch (a)
{ 
    case a <= b: //<--error 
        //Do something
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I know this can be done with an `if` / `else` statement, but I'm curious about it, why doesn't it work in a `switch` / `case` statement?

Can this be done in "C" programming?

Answer (score 4):

You could not give expression in switch case, You have to give `constant` values instead of expression in case.

> The switch statement is a control statement that handles multiple
>   selections and enumerations by passing control to one of the case
>   statements within its body

You can read more about switch [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: sure you can have expressions in `switch` cases. They just must be *constant integer expressions*.

Answer (score 2):

a <= b is `bool` expression, but `a` is `int`.

Also according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.90).aspx each case label specifies a constant value. In your case is expression, not constant.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons the language was designed to require constant case values, including:

(1) To ensure that there cannot be overlapping ranges (and that this can be checked at compile time).
(2) To make switch statements extremely performant.
(3) To be more familiar to C++ programmers (who, in the early days, were a large proportion of the new C# users).

Answer (score 0):

Because in cases you should specify possible values of a, not conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The first case will be executed if you do

This exact code won't work

```
switch(True) {
    case a <= b:
        //Do something
        break;
}
```

So the result of expression (True, in this case) is compared with the argument given to switch (True), the comparison would look like this:
"Is True == True"; which will obviously results in true and the code will run.

Comment: The code will not compile as C.

Comment: I know and really sorry for that, but I was just giving the concept of what it is. I replied half of it in javascript even in that it's true not True. Sorry but I was just telling how it takes the constant after "case" and compares it with the arguement to switch.